# Layout footer 100% width and content till footer

Tags: css, html, layout, sticky-footer

Im stuck and have no idea how to solve.
I have a sticky footer and that works fine.
But I want the footer width 100%. For that reason i have a outer div which push the footer to the bottom and a content div which is centered.

Normaly I set a background color for the full outer div. This means it that header, content and footer have the same background color. For each div i can set a custom color which overrides the white (overlay).

Because the layout has now a width of 100% i cant get the content div a background color which is pushed till the footer.

[image: Layout, outer_content is red, content is white, it should float till the bottom]

**My previous story was a little bit complicated. I will short / clearify my question.
How can I have a header and footer with a width of 100% and a content centered in the middle, background color white till the footer?
Note: the content can expand or being less as 100% height.**

Here is my used HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
  <title>Temp</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head> 
<body>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="outer_header">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="menu_block"></div>
      <div id="image_block"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div id="outer_content">
    <div id="content"> 
    dafdafdafda
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="clearfooter"></div> 
  <div id="outer_footer">Footer - | |- Footer </div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And my CSS

```
/* mac hide\*/ 
html, body {height:100%} 
/* end hide */ 
body { 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  text-align:center; /* for ie6 and under */ 
  min-width:1024px;
  background-color: #eee8d8; 
  color: #000000;
} 
#outer { 
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:1024px; 
  width:100%; /* add 2px if borders are not used */ 
  text-align:left; 
  margin:auto; 
  position:relative; 
} 

* html #outer{height:99.9%;} /*For ie as treats height as min-height anyway - also addreeses rounding bug at bottom of screen in IE*/ 
#outer_header { 
  height:280px;
  width:100%;
  float:left; 
  position:relative;
  background-color:#1f4c3f;
}  

#header { 
  height:280px;
  width:1000px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
}

#menu_block {
  width:1000px;
  height:90px;
}

#image_block {
  width:1000px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#outer_content {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
  background-color:red;
}

#content { 
  width:1000px;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;  
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#outer_footer { 
  width:100%; /* add 2px if borders are not used on the #outer div */ 
  clear:both; 
  height:50px; 
  background-color:#1f4c3f;  
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  position: absolute; 
} 
* html #outer_footer {/*only ie gets this style*/ 
  \height:52px;/* for ie5 */ 
  he\ight:50px;/* for ie6 */ 
  margin-bottom:-1px; 
} 
div,p  {margin-top:0}/*clear top margin for mozilla*/ 

#clearfooter {width:100%;height:52px;clear:both} /* to clear footer */
```

Ps. I want only use CSS if possible, no javascript

Edit:
What the result should be is

[image: Correct layout]

As you can see, picture one has 1 row white (because the texts ends over there), but i want the content filled till the sticky footer...

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want your page to look like, because I am having a hard time understanding what you want.

Comment: Hi Watson, I added a picture of the result. I'm sorry but I cant find the correct words...I hope the picture makes clear where Im looking for. Most tutorials explains the result of center a layout with sticky footer, however, i want the content centered but the footer 100%...Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hereby three solutions, depending on whished scroll behaviour.

1. [JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/rs6tu/2/) without scrollbars:

   Markup:

   ```
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   ```

   Stylesheet:

   ```
   body, html {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   body {
       background: red;
   }
   #header {
       height: 160px;
       background: #1f4c3f;
   }
   #content {
       position: absolute; 
       background: white;
       width: 500px;
       top: 160px;
       bottom: 40px;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -250px;
   }
   #footer {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       background: #1f4c3f;
       width: 100%;
       height: 40px;
   }
   ```
2. [JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/rs6tu/6/) with vertical scrollbar and footer always visible:

   Markup:

   ```
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   ```

   Stylesheet:

   ```
   body, html {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       width: 100%;
   }
   body {
       background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcYOv.png') center repeat-y;
   }
   #header {
       height: 160px;
       background: #1f4c3f;
   }
   #content {
       width: 500px;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
   #footer {
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 0;
       background: #1f4c3f;
       width: 100%;
       height: 40px;
   }
   ```
3. [JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/rs6tu/5/) with vertical scrollbar and moving footer:

   Markup:

   ```
   <div id="wrap">
       <div id="header"></div>
       <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   ```

   Stylesheet:

   ```
   body, html {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
   }
   #wrap {
       background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcYOv.png') center repeat-y;
       width: 100%;
       min-height: 100%;
   }
   #header {
       height: 160px;
       background: #1f4c3f;
   }
   #content {
       width: 500px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding-bottom: 40px;
   }
   #footer {
       position: relative;
       top: -40px;
       background: #1f4c3f;
       width: 100%;
       height: 40px;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi NGLN, its almost what i am looking for. You are in the correct direction for the content, its filled till the footer. However, when i got more text, the content and the footer stay on there position, instead of being expanded and pushed down...I should expect, there is a solution only with CSS?

Comment: I have used the third option. I used in the outer_content a image of 1px and center it.