# Filling content background till it reaches footer

Tags: html, css

I have similar problem which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453972/layout-footer-100-width-and-content-till-footer). But i couldn't make it work or i didnt understand it fully.

My problem which im trying to resolve is - I want my content background to reach footer even if there isnt enough content to be displayed. I created a simple fiddle which can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vj07e8g1/). As you can see there isnt enough content to reach footer and there is this "blue" space between content and footer. I would like to make that space grey.

HTML :

```
<div class=blue>header here</div>
<p>LOGO here</p>
<div class="blue">navigation bar here</div>
  <div class="content">
No content.
  </div>
<div class="footer">footer is here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue {
    color: #ffffff;   
    background-color: #294a70;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
.content {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
    margin-bottom:30px; 
}
.footer {
    color: #ffffff;   
    background-color: #294a70;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:30px;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-image:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Alien_Ink_2560X1600_Abstract_Background_1.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}
html {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS3 `calc()` function

the trick is, if you know the height of header & footer, you can use this function with *vh* units, `100vh` gives you screen height, just substract the height of hearder & footer from it.

E.g.

If header is 80px & Footer is 40px, i.e. total 120px, then use

```
.content{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}
```

The purpose of using min-height is if content is not present then atleast this height is applied, but if there is more content than screen then div is expanded to fit accordingly.

Updated JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vj07e8g1/5/

Comment: I was some where reading about vh units but didnt understand them, You put it simply and with example I managed to implement it on my site too. So thank you for solving this problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a flexbox layout instead:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main class="content"></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main.content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Check out this codepen example: http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/zZXXWy

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your content style:

```
min-height:400px;
```

It'll push the footer a little, but it'll do the work.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it won't do the job. I need to stretch content background no matter of screen size.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest contemporary way, depending on your browser-support requirements, would be to use CSS grids, which allows you to define rows and columns and assign certain content to be in specific places (placed by `grid-row` and `grid-column`), like follows:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
/* to force all elements to be sized including
   their padding and border-widths */
body,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-content;
}

body {
  /* To use CSS grid, forcing the child elements of
     the <body> element to adopt 'display: grid-item': */
  display: grid;

  /* defining the three columns of the grid, the first and
     third being equal fractions of the space left over after
     the second (middle) column's width of 400px is calculated */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 400px 1fr;

  /* reducing the first three rows to the minimum height needed
     to fully display their content, setting the fourth row
     to take up the remaining unoccupied space once the other
     heights are calcuated and setting the final row's height to
     30px: */
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content min-content 1fr 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oC8H.jpg);
}

body>* {
  /* setting all the child elements of the <body> to be placed
     in grid-column 2 (the central 400px-wide column): */
  grid-column: 2;
}

/* Setting the default shared styles of the .blue elements: */
.blue {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #294a70;
}

.blue.header {
  /* positioning this element in the first (one-based counting)
     row: */
  grid-row: 1
}

body>p {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.blue.navigation {
  grid-row: 3;
}

div.content {
  grid-row: 4;
  /* background-color purely to show that the space of the
     div.content element occupies the full space available: */
  background-color: #ffa;
}

div.footer {
  grid-row: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="header blue">header here</div>
<p>LOGO here</p>
<div class="blue navigation">navigation bar here</div>
<div class="content">
  No content.
</div>
<div class="footer">footer is here</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4cucyc9L/1/).

Please note that I did add a class-name to both the `.blue` elements in order to more-easily distinguish them according to their roles in the document, and from each other when placing them in the document.

Comment: As a firm hater of grid layouts, I'd hardly call this the easiest contemporary way. Opinion either way. Flexbox ftw plus it actually is supported

Comment: Well, I don't understand your hatred of a layout technique that simplifies otherwise-complex layout-creation, but thanks for at least taking the time to explain :) The reason I chose not to go with flex-box is the inherently one-dimensional approach of the flex model (two dimensions can be used with nesting, of course), whereas grids offer simple (for a given value of 'simple') two-dimensional layouts. Still: ymmv and so on :)

Comment: You chose to use css-grid because it's better in 2-directions. But this layout question is clearly in 1-direction: vertical. Hey to each their own but the way bootstrap muddles up class names and all the explanation needed for your css grid answer, one might understand my hatred for complicating what is simple in flexbox. He clearly isn't the most experienced coder to just jump in with CSS grid. You seem to like it though so perhaps I'll take a deeper look but this won't have the support so soon http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid